# Session management using authentication in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, authentication, parameters, struts2

I have an application where i login and it takes me to the next page and displays a table.

I have handled session by implementing the `SessionAware` interface. 
When i refresh the page with the refresh button on the browser or F5, it works fine. However, if i press enter on the url, it takes me to the login page because the username and password is `null`.

Please find below my java code and jsp code and `struts.xml`

**JAVA class:**

```java
public String Authentication()
{        
    //  return userInfo.getUserLoginId() + "_BUSINESS_SERVICES";
    if(j_username == null)
    {
        status="failure3";
        return status;
    }
    System.out.println("get username and get password" +j_username + j_password);


    // if no userName stored in the session,
    // check the entered userName and password
    if (j_username != null && j_password != null) {
         System.out.println("inside function");
        // add userName to the session
        sessionMap.put("j_username", j_username);
        status = otlAuthenticationController.loginAuthentication(j_username,j_password);
        if(status == "success")
        {
            this.otlUserList= otlAuthenticationController.obtainList();
            System.out.println("size is"+otlUserList.size());

        }

    }


    return status;
}

public String logout()
{
    if (sessionMap instanceof org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.SessionMap) {
        try {
            //((org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.SessionMap) sessionMap).invalidate();
            if (sessionMap.containsKey("userName")) {
            sessionMap.remove(j_username);
            System.out.println("session killed");
            status ="success";
            }
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return "success";
}
```

**JSP page:**

```jsp
<div class="label" style="margin-top:10px;"><s:text name="login.password" /></div><input id="j_password" name="j_password" type="password" placeholder="Password" size="31" autocomplete="off"/><br><br>
<div class="left" style="padding-left:150px; horizontal-align:right;text-align:center;"><input type="submit" name="login"  value=<s:text name="login"/> class="button normal normal1"  onClick="validate1()"/></div>&nbsp;
   <br> <br><s:if test="status=='failure'">
  <center><p style="color:RED" text-align :"center"><b>  Invalid username. Please enter a valid username</b></p></center>
</s:if>
<s:if test="status=='failure2'">
<center><p style="color:RED" text-align :"center"><b>  Invalid password. Please enter a valid password</b></p></center>
</s:if>
<s:if test="status=='failure3'">
  <center><p style="color:RED" text-align :"center"><b>  Login to the application to continue</b></p></center>
</s:if>
</div>
```

**struts.xml:**

```xml
<action name="logout" class ="com.opentext.planning.view.OTLAuthentication" method="logout">
       <result name="success">/WEB-INF/index.jsp</result>
       <result name="failure">/WEB-INF/error.jsp</result>
</action>       
<action name ="Otl_Homepage" 
    class="com.opentext.planning.view.OTLAuthentication" method="Authentication">
    <result name="success">/WEB-INF/Otl_Homepage.jsp</result>
   <result name="failure">/WEB-INF/index.jsp</result>
    <result name="failure2">/WEB-INF/index.jsp</result>
    <result name="failure3">/WEB-INF/index.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Comment: What is the point of returning 3 different failure results with the same jsp ? Why aren't you using camelCase for variables names ? Why is the JSP code formatted so badly ? Why one action name is lowercased and the other is capitalized ? Why one action method is lowercased and the other is capitalized ? Why sometimes `{` is inline and sometimes it is in a new line ? Dude, this matters... consider improving it. BTW login credentials should be checked in a custom interceptor, not in an action method, and that interceptor should be applied to every action except the login one...

Answer (score 0):

The required parameters are in the action context, but if you are using the action, which for some reason doesn't get parameters from the `params` interceptor, then you still can get parameters if your action implements [`ParameterAware`](http://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/ParameterAware.html).

```
public class OLTAuthentication implements ParameterAware {

private Map<String, String[]> parameters;

public void setParameters(Map<String, String[]> parameters){
  this.parameters = parameters;
} 

public String Authentication() {
    String j_username = parameters.get("j_username")[0];
    String j_password = parameters.get("j_password")[0];
    ...
```